# Vue Router Navigation Guard: Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I constantly got a maximum stack size exceeded issue when trying the codes below, it's using vue router navigation guards per-route:

```
import state from "../vuex-store/state.js";
import Editor from "../views/Editor";
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/editor",
        component: Editor,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            if (state.isAuthorized) {
                if (from.path === "/editor") {
                    next(false);
                } else {
                    next("/editor");
                }
            } else {
                next(false);
            }
        }
    }
];
```

Please kindly help explain to me why this recursion error is happening, and how can I solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? It seems like the route will never be resolved.

Comment: It's extracted from my codes. I've attached all the necessary codes for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` occurs through this expression: `next("/editor");`

If your statement is `true` you creating a infinity loop, because it triggers the `beforeEnter`-Method again.

To solve this issue simply replace

```
next("/editor");
```

with

```
next();
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. But I still have a confusion: Wouldn't the if condition    (from.path === "/editor")    control this infinite loop? If the from path is not "/editor" then it enters the "/editor" path via "next('/editor')" statement, then the "from" path now becomes "/editor" and the "to" path is "/editor" as well, then the if condition should control this situation, then it should execute "next(false);" statement, which cancels the navigation? Why this does not work?

Comment: Also spare me for another question... I understand that next(false) is to cancel the current navigation, and next("/editor") is to go to the path "/editor". But what's exactly the meaning of next() ? From the official doc it says "next(): move on to the next hook in the pipeline. If no hooks are left, the navigation is confirmed." What's the "next hook" that it means in here? Also "the navigation is confirmed", in this example does it mean it confirms the navigation to "/editor"? If yes then it goes to the path "/editor", why this time it does not trigger an infinity loop? Thank you greatly!!

Comment: You're welcome :). No it does not control the infinite loop, because it never enters the path and as a result, `from` does never get set to "/editor". You can simply check this by `console.log(from)` and you will see that `path` is always the one that you are coming from.

Comment: As you already mentioned, `next();` pointed to the next hook. Cause you try to enter the "/editor"-`path` this appears to be the next hook and you don't have to say `next("/editor)"`. Hopefully this helps you.